# IntelliJ won't detect Ruby interpreter installed using asdf-vm whatsoever

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, asdf, asdf-vm

Pretty weird stuff.
I have installed latest Ruby using asdf-vm. All works fine with the terminal - Ruby is being detected, I am able to install gems, and every create a Rails app and open it using VSCode.

Somehow, IntelliJ is detecting Ruby in `/usr/bin/ruby`. First of all, the file doesn't appear in the file system when I try to manually locate it. Also, the version of this file is different than the version I installed using asdf-vm. Next, I haven't installed Ruby using anything other than asdf-vm. Finally, I'm unable to delete the file using IntelliJ.

Now, changing the Ruby interpreter manually to `/home/jaymin/.asdf/shims/ruby` gives me the following error:

> Error configuring SDK: Unable to read RbConfig for ruby (/home/linux-user/.asdf/shims/ruby). Please make sure that /home/linux-user/.asdf/shims/ruby is a valid home path for this SDK type.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You want to read this page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/ruby-version-managers.html . In worst case you open an issue with ItelliJ like described on the end of that page. If you figure out the solution, please post it here for others to see also.

Comment: Please share your logs by creating YouTrack issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=RUBY

Comment: Okay, I've created a new issue. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-29810/IntelliJ-won-t-detect-Ruby-interpreter-installed-using-asdf-vm-w